# VBA Random Element from Array , Subscript out of Range error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a vba noob so go easy on me.

I want to select a random array element in my card_range_string array ( see random_type, last line ) but I get an "Subscript out of range" error. What can be wrong?

```
Sub generate_random()
' generates a random card

Dim random_card As Long: random_card = Int(Math.Rnd * 13) + 1
Dim random_type As String
Dim random_symbol As Variant

Dim card_Range_string() As Variant: card_Range_string = Range("A1:A4").Value
Dim card_Range_symbol() As Variant: card_Range_symbol = Range("B1:B4").Value

random_type = card_Range_string(Int(Math.Rnd * 3))

End Sub
```

Comment: I solved it. Remembered that arrays are two-dimensional so I had only missed to spell out the second dimension.
Making: random_type = card_Range_string(int(Math.Rnd*4+1),1) 
solves the issue

Comment: It is acceptable to post your own answer and accept it. That helps out future readers, as they can see that the question was solved.

Comment: ahh thank you. Will keep that in mind to next time.

Comment: i avoid the dimension mistackes by adding a line just after the dim of the vba array usually as follows:  `redim card_Range_string (1 to 4, 1 to 1)`.   (from your code example A1:A4), because if i dont, the array starts from (0,0) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Remembered that arrays are two-dimensional so I had only missed to spell out the second dimension. Making: random_type = card_Range_string(int(Math.Rnd*4+1),1) solves the issue